# Programmatically Add Links to Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-5.0

I am working on adding links to a spreadsheet of variable length through PowerShell and I am running into an error no matter how I do it. This is the loop I am currently trying to make work, which is nested within an excel comobject, with $sheet representing $excel.activeworkbook.activesheet :

```
$v = 2
foreach($i in $list){
    $r = "A"+$v
    $link = "www.url.com"
    $sheet.Hyperlinks.Add($r,$link)
    $v++
}
```

Which keeps throwing the following error:

```
Exception setting "Add": Cannot convert the "A2" value of type "string" to type "Object".
At C:\hyperlink_wip.ps1:31 char:5
+     $sheet.Hyperlinks.Add($r,$link)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

in this example, $list is a list which contains the information from one column of this spreadsheet and will always be the same length as the spreadsheet itself. The spreadsheet also has a header row, so the cells I want to hyperlink start at A2. I also tried the method outlined [here](https://learn-powershell.net/2015/10/02/quick-hits-adding-a-hyperlink-to-excel-spreadsheet/) for adding links to an excel spreadsheet but got an incorrect format error each time I tried it.

Comment: `$r` isn't a [`Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) or `Shape`. Here's the [Add Method on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx)

Comment: @BenH, you are correct, sir. Changing $r to $sheet.range("A"+$v) fixed the issue.

Comment: @BenH, if you were to post your comment as an answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$r` isn't a [`Range`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) or `Shape`. Here's the [Add Method on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490.aspx)

Here's an example of how you could use it in your code:

```
$v = 2
foreach($i in $list){
    $r = $sheet.range("A"+$v)
    $link = "www.url.com"
    $sheet.Hyperlinks.Add($r,$link)
    $v++
}
```